# calculating a mclaurin limit

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

i'm having hard time with $\lim _{x\to \infty } \frac{x(1+e^{x^2})tanx-2sin^2x}{x(tanx-x)}$

i've tried to simplify it using cos2x identity($cos2x=1-2sin^2x ->cos2x-1=-2sin^2x $, or tried to break it into 2 different fractions, but i couldn't get it to a point where i could use mclaurin in order to solve the given limit.

could you help me in that please?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the denominator:

$$x(\tan x-x)\approx x(x+\frac{x^3}3-x)=\frac{x^4}3.$$

We will probably need a fourth degree approximation at the numerator.

Then the numerator:

$$x(1+e^{x^2})\tan x-2\sin^2x\approx x\left(2+x^2\right)x\left(1+\frac{x^2}3\right)-2x^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}6\right)^2\\
=\left(\frac23+1+\frac{2\cdot2}6\right)x^4+\cdots$$

Hence the limit $$7.$$

---

Note that you can start by pulling out a factor $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ and evaluate

$$\frac{x(1+e^{x^2})\sec x-2\sin x}{\tan x-x}\approx\dfrac{x(2+x^2)\left(1+\dfrac{x^2}2\right)-2x\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}6\right)}{x+\dfrac{x^3}3-x}=\frac{\dfrac{7x^2}3+\cdots}{\dfrac{x^2}3}.$$